# Chart.js horizontal bar width

Tags: javascript, bar-chart, chart.js

I have the following bar chart:

[image: bar chart]

The above chart is generated with the following code:

```
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: data,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ]
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                borderWidth: 40,
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

As you can see, the bar width is fairly small.

My question is, how can I increase the width of each bar?

Comment: The width of the bar is defined by data?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, I'm running into the same issue but only on a Horizontal Bar Chart. @SvenKoluem the OP is referring to the width of the X axis, which in the case of ChartJS is relative to whether its a Horizontal Bar chart or regular. For the sake of conversation, we're talking about the vertical height.

Answer (score 2):

Simply increase the canvas height. For Example;

`<canvas id="horizontalbar" height="1000px"></canvas>`

Comment: Thx that helped me

Answer (score 1):

You have the `barThickness` option as mentionned in the docs here -> http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#bar-chart-chart-options

Comment: This causes categories to overlap for me.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not an official fix, it worked for me. I took advice from this link, https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/2787

I store all my values within multiple arrays, so count number of objects and multiply by a specific number and set height of your chart wrapper ( div around the chart ).

```
<div class="chart-wrapper horizontalBar" style="position: relative; height: 50vh;">
    <canvas id="chart-location"></canvas>
</div>
```

Then after the chart is drawn, set the height (location_labels is an array housing all my labels)

```
$( ".horizontalBar" ).height(location_labels.length * 30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `height` tag in `canvas` element. This solved for me.

```
<canvas id="Chart" height="50">
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

For most versions, this would solve it

```
import {Chart} from "chart.js"

Chart.defaults.datasets.bar.barThickness = 73;

//also try barPercentage, maxBarThickness
```